# How to implement k-fold cross-validation while forcing linear regression of predicted to real values to 1:1 line

Tags: r, statistics, regression, caret

I'm trying to train y as a polynomial function of x so that when the predicted y values are linearly regressed against the real y values, the relationship is on the 1:1 line ([diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Vce.png) - *The image on the right uses geom_smooth(method="lm") for demonstration, but with SMA from the lmodel2() function, the regression line is 1:1*). I'm kind of a stats amateur so I'm aware there might be problems with this, but without forcing the model tends to overestimate low values and underestimate high values. My question is: How do I introduce k-fold cross-validation using an existing package like caret or cvms? It seems like they need a model object to be returned and I can't figure out how to code my problem like that. Is there some way I can train the model by minimizing my custom metric and still return a model object with ypred and use it in k-fold CV?

This is my code for calculating the coefficients without k-fold CV:

```
data <- data.frame(
        x = c(1.514, 1.514, 1.825, 1.281, 1.118, 1.279, 1.835, 1.819, 0.462, 1.53, 1.004, 1.19, 1.275, 0.428, 0.313, 0.909, 0.995, 0.995, 0.706, 0.563, 0.827, 0.65, 0.747, 1.013, 1.013, 1.163, 1.091, 1.163, 1.091, 0.955, 0.955, 2.044, 2.044, 1.777, 1.777, 1.434, 1.393, 1.324, 0.981, 0.845, 1.595, 1.595, 1.517, 1.517, 1.403, 1.403, 0.793, 0.793, 1.016, 0.901, 0.847, 1.054, 0.877, 1.639, 1.639, 1.268, 1.268, 0.842, 0.842, 0.827, 0.777, 1.024, 1.238, 1.238, 1.702, 1.702, 0.673, 0.673, 1.256, 1.256, 0.898, 0.898, 0.66, 0.933, 0.827, 0.836, 1.122, 1.5, 1.5, 1.44, 1.44, 0.671, 0.671, 0.486, 0.486, 1.051, 1.051, 0.971, 0.538, 0.971, 0.538, 1.012, 1.012, 0.776, 0.776, 0.854, 0.854, 0.74, 0.989, 0.989),
        y = c(0.19, 0.18, 0.816, 2.568, 0.885, 0.521, 0.268, 0.885, 4.781, 1.648, 0.989, 1.614, 1.492, 0.679, 2.256, 3.17, 1.926, 1.631, 0.462, 2.48, 0.658, 0.355, 0.373, 2.31, 3.263, 1.374, 1.374, 2.637, 2.637, 2.073, 2.298, 0.257, 0.292, 0.359, 0.329, 1.329, 1.272, 3.752, 1.784, 0.76, 0.458, 0.488, 0.387, 0.387, 3.401, 1.458, 8.945, 9.12, 0.308, 0.386, 0.405, 6.444, 3.17, 0.458, 0.47, 0.572, 0.589, 1.961, 1.909, 0.636, 0.32, 1.664, 0.756, 0.851, 0.403, 0.232, 23.112, 22.042, 0.745, 0.477, 2.349, 3.01, 0.39, 0.246, 0.43, 1.407, 1.358, 0.235, 0.215, 0.595, 0.685, 2.539, 2.128, 8.097, 5.372, 0.644, 0.626, 17.715, 17.715, 6.851, 6.851, 2.146, 1.842, 3.147, 2.95, 1.127, 1.019, 8.954, 0.796, 0.758),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
optim_results <- optim(par = c(a0 = 0.3, a1 = -3.8, a2 = -1, a3 = 1, a4 = 1),
                       fn = function (params, x, y) {
                                params <- as.list(params)
                                ypred <- with(params, (a0 + (a1*x) + (a2*x^2) + (a3*x^3) + (a4*x^4)))
                                mod <- suppressMessages(lmodel2::lmodel2(ypred ~ y))$regression.results[3,]
                                line <- mod$Slope * y + mod$Intercept
                                return(sum((y - line)^2))}, 
                       x = log10(data$x),
                       y = log10(data$y))
cf <- as.numeric(optim_results$par)
data <- data %>% dplyr::mutate(ypred = 10^(cf[1] + cf[2]*log10(x) + cf[3]*log10(x)^2 + cf[4]*log10(x)^3 + cf[5]*log10(x)^4))
str(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question!

`cvms::cross_validate_fn()` allows you to cross-validate custom functions. You just have to wrap your code in a model function and a predict function as so:

**EDIT**: Added extraction of model parameters from the `optim()` output. `optim()` returns a list, which we convert to a class and then tell `coef()` how to extract the coefficients for that class.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(groupdata2)
library(cvms)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(2)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1.514, 1.514, 1.825, 1.281, 1.118, 1.279, 1.835, 1.819, 0.462, 1.53, 1.004, 1.19, 1.275, 0.428, 0.313, 0.909, 0.995, 0.995, 0.706, 0.563, 0.827, 0.65, 0.747, 1.013, 1.013, 1.163, 1.091, 1.163, 1.091, 0.955, 0.955, 2.044, 2.044, 1.777, 1.777, 1.434, 1.393, 1.324, 0.981, 0.845, 1.595, 1.595, 1.517, 1.517, 1.403, 1.403, 0.793, 0.793, 1.016, 0.901, 0.847, 1.054, 0.877, 1.639, 1.639, 1.268, 1.268, 0.842, 0.842, 0.827, 0.777, 1.024, 1.238, 1.238, 1.702, 1.702, 0.673, 0.673, 1.256, 1.256, 0.898, 0.898, 0.66, 0.933, 0.827, 0.836, 1.122, 1.5, 1.5, 1.44, 1.44, 0.671, 0.671, 0.486, 0.486, 1.051, 1.051, 0.971, 0.538, 0.971, 0.538, 1.012, 1.012, 0.776, 0.776, 0.854, 0.854, 0.74, 0.989, 0.989),
  y = c(0.19, 0.18, 0.816, 2.568, 0.885, 0.521, 0.268, 0.885, 4.781, 1.648, 0.989, 1.614, 1.492, 0.679, 2.256, 3.17, 1.926, 1.631, 0.462, 2.48, 0.658, 0.355, 0.373, 2.31, 3.263, 1.374, 1.374, 2.637, 2.637, 2.073, 2.298, 0.257, 0.292, 0.359, 0.329, 1.329, 1.272, 3.752, 1.784, 0.76, 0.458, 0.488, 0.387, 0.387, 3.401, 1.458, 8.945, 9.12, 0.308, 0.386, 0.405, 6.444, 3.17, 0.458, 0.47, 0.572, 0.589, 1.961, 1.909, 0.636, 0.32, 1.664, 0.756, 0.851, 0.403, 0.232, 23.112, 22.042, 0.745, 0.477, 2.349, 3.01, 0.39, 0.246, 0.43, 1.407, 1.358, 0.235, 0.215, 0.595, 0.685, 2.539, 2.128, 8.097, 5.372, 0.644, 0.626, 17.715, 17.715, 6.851, 6.851, 2.146, 1.842, 3.147, 2.95, 1.127, 1.019, 8.954, 0.796, 0.758),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Fold data
# Will do 10-fold repeated cross-validation (10 reps)
data <- fold(
  data = data,
  k = 10,  # Num folds
  num_fold_cols = 10  # Num repetitions
)

# Write a model function from your code
# This ignores the formula and hyperparameters but
# you could pass values through those if you wanted
# to try different formulas or hyperparameter values
model_fn <- function(train_data, formula, hyperparameters){
  out <- optim(par = c(a0 = 0.3, a1 = -3.8, a2 = -1, a3 = 1, a4 = 1),
        fn = function (params, x, y) {
          params <- as.list(params)
          ypred <- with(params, (a0 + (a1*x) + (a2*x^2) + (a3*x^3) + (a4*x^4)))
          mod <- suppressMessages(lmodel2::lmodel2(ypred ~ y))$regression.results[3,]
          line <- mod$Slope * y + mod$Intercept
          return(sum((y - line)^2))},
        x = log10(train_data$x),
        y = log10(train_data$y))

  # Convert output to an S3 class
  # so we can extract parameters with coef()
  class(out) <- "OptimModel"

  out
}

# Tell coef() how to extract the parameters
# This can modified if you need more info from the optim() output
# Just return a named list
coef.OptimModel <- function(object) {
  object$par
}

# Write a predict function from your code
predict_fn <- function(test_data, model, formula, hyperparameters, train_data){
  cf <- as.numeric(model$par)
  test_data %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      ypred = 10^(cf[1] + cf[2]*log10(x) + cf[3]*log10(x)^2 + cf[4]*log10(x)^3 + cf[5]*log10(x)^4)
    ) %>%
    .[["ypred"]]
}

# Cross-validate the model
cv <- cross_validate_fn(
  data = data,
  model_fn = model_fn,
  predict_fn = predict_fn,
  formulas = c("y ~ x"), # Not currently used by the model function
  fold_cols = paste0('.folds_', seq_len(10)),
  type = 'gaussian'
)
#> Will cross-validate 1 models. This requires fitting 100 model instances.

# Check output
cv
# A tibble: 1 × 17
  Fixed  RMSE   MAE NRMSE(I…¹  RRSE   RAE RMSLE Predic…² Results  Coeffi…³ Folds
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>   <list>   <list>   <int>
1 x      4.00  2.31      2.66  1.47  1.17 0.662 <tibble> <tibble> <tibble>   100
# … with 6 more variables: `Fold Columns` <int>, `Convergence Warnings` <int>,
#   `Other Warnings` <int>, `Warnings and Messages` <list>, Process <list>,
#   Dependent <chr>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​`NRMSE(IQR)`,
#   ²​Predictions, ³​Coefficients
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'm having an issue with your example... the results look fine but the coefficients are all NA. Am I misinterpreting the results? Does it not like the optim() function or dummy formula?

Comment: @22billionchickens It uses the `parameters::model_parameters` to extract model parameters. Perhaps they don't support `optim` objects? Default when parameter extraction fails is to return the `NA`s.

Comment: @22billionchickens `optim` just returns a list, so it's probably hard to support detection of the coefs for optim models. If you need the coefficients from the cross-validation (often people don't need them, since you'll have `folds x repetitions x hyperparameter combinations` sets of coefficients), you could perhaps wrap the optim call in a class that works with `coef()` or `parameters::model_parameters()`? Let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: I've been messing around with wrappers but I'm not making any headway :( Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @22billionchickens I added a solution to the parameter extraction to the example :-) Basically, we make the output a class and tell `coef()` how to deal with it.

Comment: That's a cool trick! For some reason it's still not working here (coefficients are still all NA)... I've tried updating groupdata2, cvms, and parameters packages, but no luck.

Comment: Really? When I run the above code, only the p-values are NA:

`
| Fold Column  Fold term  estimate p.value
| 1 .folds_1          1 a0       0.152 NA     
| 2 .folds_1          1 a1      -3.31  NA     
 ...
`

Comment: Could you post the code you are running and the output?

Comment: I was running the example code but must have forgotten to clear memory or restart R after updating one of those packages! Now it is working (coefficients are there and p-values are NA as you mentioned). Thanks! :)

Comment: Perfect :D Good luck with your analysis!
Please upvote and mark as resolved so people will see the answer when trying the same :)